# Search and replace operations in multi-dimensional data frame with time series data

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, plyr, reshape2, data-manipulation

I'm looking for a more concise and/or efficient way to search and replace values in something that I guess you could call a multi-dimensional data frame (or something that could be represented as such): a data frame containing snapshots of time series taken/recorded over time (e.g. each month).

In the following example, there are

- 2 time series (`A`, `B`),
- each with 3 observations,
- each recorded at 3 data states (`2015-07-01`, `2015-08-01`, `2015-09-01`)

My current solution works, but I feel like I'm not really making use of more advanced ways of data manipulation in R (e.g. clever matrix algebra/vectorized algorithms, functionality of packages `plyr`, `dplyr` or `reshape2`, etc.).

### Example data

```
datastates <- c("2015-07-01", "2015-08-01", "2015-09-01")
id <- c("A", "B")
actuals <- c(100, 25, NA)
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(id), function(ii) {
  id_this <- id[ii]
  fac_1 <- 1 + ii/10

  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(datastates), function(state) {
    fac_2 <- fac_1 + state * 2
    actuals_2 <- ceiling(actuals * fac_2)
    date <- as.POSIXlt(datastates[state])
    date_prev <- date
    date_prev$mon <- date_prev$mon - 1
    date_vec <- seq(date_prev, length.out = 3, by = "1 month")

    data.frame(
      id = id_this,
      timebucket = as.character(date_vec),
      datastate = datastates[state],
      t = c("t-1", "t", "t+1"),
      actual = actuals_2,
      naive = NA,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  }))
}))
dat
   # id timebucket  datastate   t actual naive
# 1   A 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    310    NA
# 2   A 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t     78    NA
# 3   A 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 4   A 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    510    NA
# 5   A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    128    NA
# 6   A 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 7   A 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    710    NA
# 8   A 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    178    NA
# 9   A 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 10  B 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    320    NA
# 11  B 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t     80    NA
# 12  B 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 13  B 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    520    NA
# 14  B 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    130    NA
# 15  B 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 16  B 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    720    NA
# 17  B 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    180    NA
# 18  B 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA    NA
```

### Replacement logic

For *each* time series, I need to replace values according to the following logic:

1. The actual value (variable `actual`) of the timebucket that "corresponds" to the datastate (e.g. timebucket `2015-07-01` for datastate `2015-07-01`, also denoted with `t = t`) needs to be replaced with the value of the same timebucket of the **next** datastate (e.g. `2015-08-01`)
2. The naive (random walk) forecast is the value of variable `actual` of the first observation for a datastate (e.g. timbucket `2015-06-01` for datastate `2015-07-01`). All observations **after** the first timebucket need to have this value for variable `naive`

This is what the data should look like after the replacements:

```
   id timebucket  datastate   t actual naive
1   A 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    310    NA
2   A 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    510   310
3   A 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA   310
4   A 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    510    NA
5   A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    710   510
6   A 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA   510
7   A 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    710    NA
8   A 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    178   710
9   A 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA   710
10  B 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    320    NA
11  B 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    520   320
12  B 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA   320
13  B 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    520    NA
14  B 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    720   520
15  B 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA   520
16  B 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    720    NA
17  B 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    180   720
18  B 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA   720
```

### Current solution

Correct actuals:

```
dat_2 <- dplyr::arrange(dat, id, timebucket, datastate)

correctActuals <- function(dat) {
  idx <- which(dat$datastate == dat$timebucket)
  if (length(idx) && idx < nrow(dat)) {
    dat[idx, "actual"] <- dat[idx + 1, "actual"]
  }
  dat
}
dat_3 <- plyr::ddply(dat_2, c("id", "timebucket"), correctActuals)
dat_3
#    id timebucket  datastate   t actual naive
# 1   A 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    310    NA
# 2   A 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    510    NA
# 3   A 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    510    NA
# 4   A 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 5   A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    710    NA
# 6   A 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    710    NA
# 7   A 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 8   A 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    178    NA
# 9   A 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 10  B 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    320    NA
# 11  B 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    520    NA
# 12  B 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    520    NA
# 13  B 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 14  B 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    720    NA
# 15  B 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    720    NA
# 16  B 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA    NA
# 17  B 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    180    NA
# 18  B 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA    NA
```

Correct naive:

```
correctNaive <- function(dat) {
  timebucket_prev <- as.POSIXlt(dat$datastate)
  timebucket_prev$mon <- timebucket_prev$mon - 1
  idx <- which(dat$timebucket == as.character(timebucket_prev))
  if (length(idx)) {
    dat[(idx + 1):nrow(dat), "naive"] <- dat[idx, "actual"]
  }
  dat
}
dat_4 <- plyr::ddply(dat_3, c("id", "datastate"), correctNaive)
dat_4
#    id timebucket  datastate   t actual naive
# 1   A 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    310    NA
# 2   A 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    510   310
# 3   A 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA   310
# 4   A 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    510    NA
# 5   A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    710   510
# 6   A 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA   510
# 7   A 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    710    NA
# 8   A 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    178   710
# 9   A 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA   710
# 10  B 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    320    NA
# 11  B 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    520   320
# 12  B 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA   320
# 13  B 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    520    NA
# 14  B 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    720   520
# 15  B 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA   520
# 16  B 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    720    NA
# 17  B 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    180   720
# 18  B 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA   720
```

Arranged result:

```
dplyr::arrange(dat_4, id, datastate, timebucket)
#    id timebucket  datastate   t actual naive
# 1   A 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    310    NA
# 2   A 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    510   310
# 3   A 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA   310
# 4   A 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    510    NA
# 5   A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    710   510
# 6   A 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA   510
# 7   A 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    710    NA
# 8   A 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    178   710
# 9   A 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA   710
# 10  B 2015-06-01 2015-07-01 t-1    320    NA
# 11  B 2015-07-01 2015-07-01   t    520   320
# 12  B 2015-08-01 2015-07-01 t+1     NA   320
# 13  B 2015-07-01 2015-08-01 t-1    520    NA
# 14  B 2015-08-01 2015-08-01   t    720   520
# 15  B 2015-09-01 2015-08-01 t+1     NA   520
# 16  B 2015-08-01 2015-09-01 t-1    720    NA
# 17  B 2015-09-01 2015-09-01   t    180   720
# 18  B 2015-10-01 2015-09-01 t+1     NA   720
```